# Unweighted vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, weight-painting

A custom model exporter gives me an error: "Could not load a vertex: Unweighted vertex found !"

How can I find these vertices ?

Comment: How about a little more vital information?

Comment: I need to find the unweighted vertices on my mesh.

Comment: I cannot see any *vital* Information in that. How about starting with the *obvious things*? Like which exporter do you use *exactly*? How does your model look like? Please take a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - especially the part where it says **"Be specific"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming either :

- all groups in the object correspond to the armature (no additional groups) and there is no need to check if bones are deforming bones
- or there is no armature consideration in the context

you can use this script :

```
import bpy

def selectUnweightedVerts( obj ):

    for vertex in obj.data.vertices: #go through the vertices
        vertex.select = False #by default deselect
        zeroWeight = 0
        for group in vertex.groups: #count the amount of 0 weight
            if group.weight == 0:
                zeroWeight += 1

        if zeroWeight == len(vertex.groups) : #select if all unweighted
            vertex.select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT') #for an unknown reason, selecting in edit mode does not work

obj = bpy.context.active_object

selectUnweightedVerts( obj )
```